# discord.py — как отследить view timeout и отключить кнопки?

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно, чтобы по прошествии времени в моём `view` отключались кнопки.

Как я могу это реализовать?

```py
class test(commands.Cog):
    @app_commands.command(name='test', description='timeout test')
    async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        testBTN = Button(label="test", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
        view = View(timeout=120)
        view.add_item(testBTN)
        view.on_timeout = print('Time is out')
        await interaction.response.send_message('text', view=view,ephemeral=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать on_timeout в коде своего представления, чтобы удалить кнопки:

```
def __init__(self, ctx, summary, ranked, matches):
super().__init__(timeout=600)
    self.summary = summary

async def on_timeout(self):
    await self.message.edit(embed=self.summary, view=None)
```

Но вам также нужно немного отредактировать код команды:

```
view = ViewSwitch(ctx, summary, ranked, matches)
```

view.message = await ctx.send(embed=summary, view=view)

Comment: В моём случае так не выйдет, потому что мой `view` идёт в классе кога.